# "/pl061@9030000:clocks: cell 0 is not a phandle reference" when compiling a dts file

Tags: linux-device-driver, qemu, gpio, device-tree

I used "-machine dumpdtb=dtb.dtb" in qemu command to extract dtb file of the arm 'virt' machine. Then I converted the dtb file to dts file using dtc. And I tried to make that dts file backto dtb. But I'm seeing a warning message like this (only showing the first warning).

```
dtb.dts:284.3-21: Warning (clocks_property): /pl061@9030000:clocks: cell 0 is not a phandle reference
```

The warning comes from the line in the dts

```
pl061@9030000 {
    phandle = <0x8003>;
    clock-names = "apb_pclk";
    clocks = <0x8000>;               <==== this line
    interrupts = <0x00 0x07 0x04>;
    gpio-controller;
    #gpio-cells = <0x02>;
    compatible = "arm,pl061\0arm,primecell";
    reg = <0x00 0x9030000 0x00 0x1000>;
};
```

I've looked at Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/pl061-gpio.yaml but there is no explanation about the property clocks. I guess it's the clock frequency for the gpio but somehow the dtc program thinks it is a phandle. and I couldn't find any use of 'clocks' in the pl061 driver. Can I just safely ignore that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a phandle to the /apb-pclk node elsewhere in the dtb. The "clocks" property is part of the "arm,primecell" binding, documented here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/primecell.txt

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks again. So it was from the phandle generation of dtc. I've checked even with these warnings, the phandle referencing is preserved (I tried dtb->dts->dtb->dts) so it seems ignorable. If I delete phandle=<0x8000> and add a label to the apb-clock, and let other nodes use that new phandle, the warnings go away. But this seems unnecessary. I'm curious why dtc doesn't add lables for nodes that are referenced and let other nodes use that label as the phandle.